# gnuplot does not typeset the y-label

Tags: gnuplot

I use gnuplot 5.4.5 for processing the following script:

```
set key enhanced font "Monospaced,13"
set grid

set style line 1 \
    linecolor rgb '#a82828' \
    linetype 1 linewidth 3 \
    pointtype 5 pointsize 1.0

set xlabel "Entropy"
set xrange [-0.05:1.05]
set ylabel "Amortized work"

set terminal png enhanced font "Monospaced,13" size 500,350
set output 'EntropyToAmortizedWork.png'

plot 'EntropyToAmortizedWork.dat' with linespoints linestyle 1 notitle

replot
exit
```

The file `EntropyToAmortizedWork.dat` lives [here](https://gist.github.com/coderodde/84d0c1af0dd1a6344f0429b9d610aa2c).

All in all, I get:

[image: Missing ylabel]

Clearly, we have a typesetting artifact. How could I deal with it?

Comment: Before you continue to ask further questions, what about your earlier questions? Are any of the answers helpful and/or solved your problems? If yes, please upvote and/or accept. If not, please clarify.

Comment: I still have so many issues, I lost the track of them all. You are asking impossible.

Comment: So, you even haven't tried earlier suggestions to earlier questions, but you have time to ask new questions? Interesting...

Comment: @theozh Note that the 3 previous questions deal with the cairolatex terminal. This one relies on the png terminal.

Comment: @theozh Don't worry, I will take a closer look to your previous suggestions, but now, I have to deal with this one, first things first.

Comment: Well, first comes first. I can reproduce this. Seems to be a new bug in 5.4.5, go back to 5.4.4. Or use terminal pngcairo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this on Win10 with gnuplot 5.4.5 and terminal `png`, but not with gnuplot 5.4.4.
Even terminal `pngcairo` seems to have a problem with 5.4.5, check the missing horizontal lines on some xticlabels.

So, suggested solution would be to go back to gnuplot 5.4.4 or earlier versions.

This would be a minimal script (no need for data).

**Script:**

```
### wrong ylabel with 5.4.5 and png terminal
reset session

set ylabel "This is the y-label"

set term png size 640,384
set output "SO74179232_png.png"
plot x

set term pngcairo size 640,384
set output "SO74179232_pngcairo.png"
plot x

set output
### end of script
```

**Results:**

gnuplot 5.4.5, terminal `png`

[image]

gnuplot 5.4.5, terminal `pngcairo`

[image]

gnuplot 5.4.4, terminal `png`

[image]

gnuplot 5.4.4, terminal `pngcairo`

[image]

Comment: There was no change to the gnuplot code for either the png terminal or the cairo terminal between version 5.4.4 and 5.4.5.  None. Zero. So any difference you see here must be do to changes in the support libraries (*.dll files).

Comment: @Ethan, thank you for this info. Do you maybe know which these libraries (.dll) are? Are these just one .dll per terminal or maybe several? In the terminal `png` in 5.4.5 case, the characters seem to be rotated by 90° but not the label as a whole. Is this just for Windows or do you see it also under Linux?

Comment: There has been a lot of churn in the font handling components of the pango library, so I would guess either that one or the fontconfig library itself. Or possibly libfreetype.  See discussions and specific bad library version reports attached to issues #2194 #2397 #2512 on the gnuplot bug tracker. This must surely affect lots of other programs in the larger Windows world, so I would guess there are tips and pointers on other forums.