# Graph issues in Gnuplot - It doesn't fully draw

Tags: graph, gnuplot, simulation, physics

I was following the code used on this gravity assist/swing simulation on this site: [site about gravity assist](https://hirossoliloquy.blogspot.com/2018/10/swing-by-gravity-assist-simulation.html?sc=1707851482507#c3374035491874321169). The first code worked for me, but not the graph. I think, the error has something to do with the actual plotting, as the mathematics behind the velocity and such should be working. The code for the graph can be seen here:

```
# Setting --------------------
reset
set key right top
set term gif animate delay 4 size 1280,720
set grid
end = 1e3*10
set xr[0:end]
set yr[0:5*1e3]
set xl "{/Times:Italic t} [s]" font "Times New Roman, 20"
set yl "{/Times:Italic v} [m/s]" font "Times New Roman, 20"
set size ratio 720./1280.

# Parameter --------------------
G    =    6.674 * 1e-11              # gravitational constant    [m3 / kg s2]
R    =    6.371 * 1e6                # radius of the earth       [m]
M    =    5.972 * 1e24               # weight of the earth       [kg]
r    =    1.737 * 1e6                # radius of the moon        [m]
m    =    7.348 * 1e0                # weight of the moon        [kg]

dt    =    10                        # Time step                 [s]
v2    =    0.2*sqrt(2*G*M/R)         # Second cosmic velocity
dh    =    dt/6.0                    # Coefficient for Runge-Kutta 4th

lim1    = 30                         # Stop time
lim2    = end/dt                     # Time limit

dis        = 200                     # Start to disappear
cut        = 5                       # Decimation

# Function --------------------
# RK4
r(x, y, z, w)  = (sqrt(x**2 + z**2))**3
f1(x, y, z, w) = y
f2(x, y, z, w) = -G * M * x / r(x, y, z, w)
f3(x, y, z, w) = w
f4(x, y, z, w) = -G * M * z / r(x, y, z, w)

rk4x(x, y, z, w) = (k1 = f1(x, y, z, w),\
     k2 = f1(x + dt*k1/2., y + dt*k1/2., z + dt*k1/2., w + dt*k1/2.),\
     k3 = f1(x + dt*k1/2., y + dt*k1/2., z + dt*k1/2., w + dt*k1/2.),\
     k4 = f1(x + dt*k3, y + dt*k3, z + dt*k3, w + dt*k3),\
     dh * (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4))
rk4y(x, y, z, w) = (k1 = f2(x, y, z, w),\
     k2 = f2(x + dt*k1/2., y + dt*k1/2., z + dt*k1/2., w + dt*k1/2.),\
     k3 = f2(x + dt*k1/2., y + dt*k1/2., z + dt*k1/2., w + dt*k1/2.),\
     k4 = f2(x + dt*k3, y + dt*k3, z + dt*k3, w + dt*k3),\
     dh * (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4))
rk4z(x, y, z, w) = (k1 = f3(x, y, z, w),\
     k2 = f3(x + dt*k1/2., y + dt*k1/2., z + dt*k1/2., w + dt*k1/2.),\
     k3 = f3(x + dt*k1/2., y + dt*k1/2., z + dt*k1/2., w + dt*k1/2.),\
     k4 = f3(x + dt*k3, y + dt*k3, z + dt*k3, w + dt*k3),\
     dh * (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4))
rk4w(x, y, z, w) = (k1 = f4(x, y, z, w),\
     k2 = f4(x + dt*k1/2., y + dt*k1/2., z + dt*k1/2., w + dt*k1/2.),\
     k3 = f4(x + dt*k1/2., y + dt*k1/2., z + dt*k1/2., w + dt*k1/2.),\
     k4 = f4(x + dt*k3, y + dt*k3, z + dt*k3, w + dt*k3),\
     dh * (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4))

# Time
Time(t) = sprintf("{/Times:Italic t} = %d [s]", t)

# Parameter
Para(th) = sprintf("{/Times:Normal=20 {/Symbol-Oblique:Italic q} = %d", th)

# Plot --------------------
# Initiate value
t = 0.0
th = 60
rad = pi/180.*th

# Earth
ve = 10000.
xe = 0.8e7

# Filename
filename = sprintf("graph ve=%+0d th=%02d.gif", ve, th)
set output filename

# Satellite 1
x1 = 0.                                # x
y1 = v2*cos(rad)                       # vx
z1 = 13e7                              # y
w1 = -v2*sin(rad)                      # vy

# Satellite 2
x2 = 0.                                # x
y2 = v2*cos(rad)                       # vx
z2 = 12e7                              # y
w2 = -v2*sin(rad)                      # vy

# Satellite 3
x3 = 0.                                # x
y3 = v2*cos(rad)                       # vx
z3 = 11e7                              # y
w3 = -v2*sin(rad)                      # vy

# Draw initiate state for lim1 steps
do for [i = 1:lim1] {
 # Parameter and v2 line
 set label 1 left at graph 0.05, graph 0.95 Para(th)
 set arrow 1 nohead from 0, v2 to end, v2 lc rgb 'black' lw 4

 # Display key
 plot 1/0 lw 3 lc rgb 'red' t "{/Times:Italic=20 v_{1}}  ",\
   1/0 lw 3 lc rgb 'blue' t "{/Times:Italic=20 v_{2}}  ",\
   1/0 lw 3 lc rgb 'green' t "{/Times:Italic=20 v_{3}}  "
}

# Update for lim2 steps
do for [i = 1:lim2] {
 t = t + dt

 # Earth
 xe = xe + ve*dt

 # Satellite 1
 vold = sqrt(y1**2+w1**2)              # Old
 x1 = x1 + rk4x(x1-xe, y1, z1, w1)
 y1 = y1 + rk4y(x1-xe, y1, z1, w1)
 z1 = z1 + rk4z(x1-xe, y1, z1, w1)
 w1 = w1 + rk4w(x1-xe, y1, z1, w1)
 vnew    = sqrt(y1**2+w1**2)           # New
 set arrow 3*(i-1)+2 nohead from t, vold to t, vnew lc rgb 'red' lw 2

 # Satellite 2
 vold = sqrt(y2**2+w2**2)              # Old
 x2 = x2 + rk4x(x2-xe, y2, z2, w2)
 y2 = y2 + rk4y(x2-xe, y2, z2, w2)
 z2 = z2 + rk4z(x2-xe, y2, z2, w2)
 w2 = w2 + rk4w(x2-xe, y2, z2, w2)
 vnew = sqrt(y2**2+w2**2)              # New
 set arrow 3*(i-1)+3 nohead from t, vold to t, vnew lc rgb 'blue' lw 2

 # Satellite 3
 vold = sqrt(y3**2+w3**2)              # Old
 x3 = x3 + rk4x(x3-xe, y3, z3, w3)
 y3 = y3 + rk4y(x3-xe, y3, z3, w3)
 z3 = z3 + rk4z(x3-xe, y3, z3, w3)
 w3 = w3 + rk4w(x3-xe, y3, z3, w3)
 vnew = sqrt(y3**2+w3**2)              # New
 set arrow 3*(i-1)+4 nohead from t, vold to t, vnew lc rgb 'green' lw 2

 # Decimate and plot
 if(i%cut==0){
  plot 1/0 lw 3 lc rgb 'red'   t "{/Times:Italic=20 v_{1}}  ",\
    1/0 lw 3 lc rgb 'blue'  t "{/Times:Italic=20 v_{2}}  ",\
    1/0 lw 3 lc rgb 'green' t "{/Times:Italic=20 v_{3}}  "
 }
}

set out
```

This always results in the following for me however:

[image: Only a part of the graph is drawn]

when it's supposed to look like this:

[image: as seen on the website].

I hope anyone can help, and I am sorry if the post was worded weirdly, first time using stackoverflow

I tried changing some values, but I am not quite sure. I also tried finding the old 5.2 Gnuplot, as that or an older version was used by the guy from the website. However I couldn't find the old version, but perhaps has that something to do with the problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I tried your script with gnuplot 5.2.0 and I get the expected result, however, not with gnuplot 5.4. I don't know yet why. I will think about it. But as a temporary fix you could download older gnuplot versions [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/gnuplot/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This is a revised answer, after more investigation)

Many of the arrows in this plot are very short. So short that they would span less than one pixel of the output image.  Gnuplot 5.2 *always* drew an arrow, no matter how short.  The result was that much of the visible line in the plot consisted of single-pixel "arrows".

Gnuplot 5.4 does not draw anything for the shaft of such a short arrow and would not draw anything for the arrowhead either.  This is less of a problem for other gnuplot terminals either because they are vector-based rather than pixel based or they implement "oversampling" so that they can specify coordinates with sub-pixel precision.

Possible work-arounds:

(1) Modify the script to guarantee that the arrow is always of some minimum length. Here is my go at it

```
# Set minimum arrow size
tiny = 25.0
...
 vnew    = sqrt(y1**2+w1**2)           # New
 if (abs((vnew - vold)) < tiny) { vnew = vold + tiny * sgn(vnew-vold) }
 set arrow 3*(i-1)+2 nohead from t, vold to t, vnew lc rgb 'red' lw 2
...
 vnew = sqrt(y2**2+w2**2)              # New
 if (abs((vnew - vold)) < tiny) { vnew = vold + tiny * sgn(vnew-vold) }
 set arrow 3*(i-1)+3 nohead from t, vold to t, vnew lc rgb 'blue' lw 2
...
 vnew = sqrt(y3**2+w3**2)              # New
 if (abs((vnew - vold)) < tiny) { vnew = vold + tiny * sgn(vnew-vold) }
 set arrow 3*(i-1)+4 nohead from t, vold to t, vnew lc rgb 'green' lw 2
```

Output attached below.  I don't know what went wrong with the y-axis label or the theta but that's a problem for another day.
[image]

(2) If you upgrade all the way to gnuplot version 6 you could use the webp terminal to generate the animation rather than gif.  The only lines you would need to change are

```
set terminal webp animate delay 4 size 1280,720
set output 'filename.webp'
```

This has the side benefit of producing a much smaller animation file (that's what webp is designed for).

Comment: Thanks so much it worked by adding the code! I will also try to upgrade to gnuplot version 6 later and try to get it to work. But thank I alot, I struggled quite a bit.

Comment: the buggy y-axis label is maybe somehow related to a similar issue with the png terminal? https://stackoverflow.com/q/74179232/7295599

Answer (score 0):

Just for the records. This script looks partly a bit strange to me.

- why drawing everything as arrows and plotting `1/0`?
- why not calculating and printing the data into a datablock and plotting everything with lines?
- what is the purpose of the first loop `do for [i = 1:lim1]`, where nothing depends  on `i`. Plotting the same arrow 30 times? Some kind of initial delay with 30 frames?

Here is a suggestion which is shorter and basically gives the same result and in addition the calculated data in a datablock (which also could be saved into a file).

**Script:** (for some strange reasons works only for gnuplot>=5.2.4)

```
### plot animated GIF
# Setting --------------------
reset
set key right top
set term gif animate delay 4 size 640,384# 1280,720
set grid
end = 1e3*10
set xr[0:end]
set yr[0:5*1e3]
set xl "t [s]"
set yl "v [m/s]"
set size ratio 720./1280.

# Parameter --------------------
G    =    6.674 * 1e-11              # gravitational constant    [m3 / kg s2]
R    =    6.371 * 1e6                # radius of the earth       [m]
M    =    5.972 * 1e24               # weight of the earth       [kg]
r    =    1.737 * 1e6                # radius of the moon        [m]
m    =    7.348 * 1e0                # weight of the moon        [kg]

dt    =    10                        # Time step                 [s]
v2    =    0.2*sqrt(2*G*M/R)         # Second cosmic velocity
dh    =    dt/6.0                    # Coefficient for Runge-Kutta 4th

lim1    = 30                         # Stop time
lim2    = end/dt                     # Time limit

dis        = 200                     # Start to disappear
cut        = 5                       # Decimation

# Function --------------------
# RK4
r(x, y, z, w)  = (sqrt(x**2 + z**2))**3
f1(x, y, z, w) = y
f2(x, y, z, w) = -G * M * x / r(x, y, z, w)
f3(x, y, z, w) = w
f4(x, y, z, w) = -G * M * z / r(x, y, z, w)

rk4x(x, y, z, w) = (k1 = f1(x, y, z, w),\
     k2 = f1(x + dt*k1/2., y + dt*k1/2., z + dt*k1/2., w + dt*k1/2.),\
     k3 = f1(x + dt*k1/2., y + dt*k1/2., z + dt*k1/2., w + dt*k1/2.),\
     k4 = f1(x + dt*k3, y + dt*k3, z + dt*k3, w + dt*k3),\
     dh * (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4))
rk4y(x, y, z, w) = (k1 = f2(x, y, z, w),\
     k2 = f2(x + dt*k1/2., y + dt*k1/2., z + dt*k1/2., w + dt*k1/2.),\
     k3 = f2(x + dt*k1/2., y + dt*k1/2., z + dt*k1/2., w + dt*k1/2.),\
     k4 = f2(x + dt*k3, y + dt*k3, z + dt*k3, w + dt*k3),\
     dh * (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4))
rk4z(x, y, z, w) = (k1 = f3(x, y, z, w),\
     k2 = f3(x + dt*k1/2., y + dt*k1/2., z + dt*k1/2., w + dt*k1/2.),\
     k3 = f3(x + dt*k1/2., y + dt*k1/2., z + dt*k1/2., w + dt*k1/2.),\
     k4 = f3(x + dt*k3, y + dt*k3, z + dt*k3, w + dt*k3),\
     dh * (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4))
rk4w(x, y, z, w) = (k1 = f4(x, y, z, w),\
     k2 = f4(x + dt*k1/2., y + dt*k1/2., z + dt*k1/2., w + dt*k1/2.),\
     k3 = f4(x + dt*k1/2., y + dt*k1/2., z + dt*k1/2., w + dt*k1/2.),\
     k4 = f4(x + dt*k3, y + dt*k3, z + dt*k3, w + dt*k3),\
     dh * (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4))

# Time
Time(t) = sprintf("t = %d [s]", t)

# Parameter
Para(th) = sprintf("θ = %d", th)

# Plot --------------------
# Initiate value
t = 0.0
th = 60
rad = pi/180.*th

# Earth
ve = 10000.
xe = 0.8e7

# Filename
filename = sprintf("graph ve=%+0d th=%02d.gif", ve, th)
set output filename

# Satellite 1
x1 = 0.                                # x
y1 = v2*cos(rad)                       # vx
z1 = 13e7                              # y
w1 = -v2*sin(rad)                      # vy

# Satellite 2
x2 = 0.                                # x
y2 = v2*cos(rad)                       # vx
z2 = 12e7                              # y
w2 = -v2*sin(rad)                      # vy

# Satellite 3
x3 = 0.                                # x
y3 = v2*cos(rad)                       # vx
z3 = 11e7                              # y
w3 = -v2*sin(rad)                      # vy

# Draw initiate state
# Parameter and v2 line
set label 1 left at graph 0.05, graph 0.95 Para(th)
set arrow 1 nohead from 0, v2 to end, v2 lc rgb 'black' lw 4

set print $Data

    # Update for lim2 steps
    do for [i = 1:lim2] {
        t = t + dt

        # Earth
        xe = xe + ve*dt

        # Satellite 1
        x1 = x1 + rk4x(x1-xe, y1, z1, w1)
        y1 = y1 + rk4y(x1-xe, y1, z1, w1)
        z1 = z1 + rk4z(x1-xe, y1, z1, w1)
        w1 = w1 + rk4w(x1-xe, y1, z1, w1)
        vs1    = sqrt(y1**2+w1**2)

        # Satellite 2
        x2 = x2 + rk4x(x2-xe, y2, z2, w2)
        y2 = y2 + rk4y(x2-xe, y2, z2, w2)
        z2 = z2 + rk4z(x2-xe, y2, z2, w2)
        w2 = w2 + rk4w(x2-xe, y2, z2, w2)
        vs2 = sqrt(y2**2+w2**2)

        # Satellite 3
        x3 = x3 + rk4x(x3-xe, y3, z3, w3)
        y3 = y3 + rk4y(x3-xe, y3, z3, w3)
        z3 = z3 + rk4z(x3-xe, y3, z3, w3)
        w3 = w3 + rk4w(x3-xe, y3, z3, w3)
        vs3 = sqrt(y3**2+w3**2)

        # Decimate and plot
        if(i%cut==0){
            print t, vs1, vs2, vs3
        }
    }
set print

do for [i=1:|$Data|] {
    plot $Data every ::::i u 1:2 w l lw 3 lc rgb 'red'   t "v_{1}",\
            '' every ::::i u 1:3 w l lw 3 lc rgb 'blue'  t "v_{2}",\
            '' every ::::i u 1:4 w l lw 3 lc rgb 'green' t "v_{3}"
}
set output
### end of script
```

**Result:** `graph ve=+10000 th=60.gif`

[image]

Comment: How exactly do I get the calculated data in a datablock? I still new to Gnuplot

Comment: @FrederikLe you have the data already in the datablock `$Data`, but you can add the line `set print "SO77990998.dat"; print $Data; set print` at the end and the data will be written into the file `SO77990998.dat`. Actually, the whole script could be optimized further.

Comment: How exactly is it you would optimize it further? I can tell, from your original answer, that arrows and plotting 1/0 isn't optimal, but I am not sure how I would go about printing the data and plotting it with lines?

Comment: @FrederikLe not sure I understand your question. The script above **is** plotting it with lines, i.e. `w l`. Where do you want to *print* the data? About optimization I mean, e.g. `f1(x,y,z,w) = y`. If the function only depends on `y` why to I need `x,z,w` as arguments?